# How to move lamp switch from inline to separate wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a few lamps around the house which all have an inline switch. It makes it very inconvenient to use:

[image: schema showing how switch is on the wire towards the socket and away from bed]

I would like to have the switch on a different wire that goes towards the bed instead:

[image: schema of desired configuration where there's a new wire towards the bed, which contains the lamp switch]

What is the name of the switch for this ? I guess I can find wiring schema once I know the name, but if you can advise also on how to wire it, it will be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have seen in a different comment about the danger of 220V. Yes, two of these lamps are connected to the mains. One other is USB, so 5V.

Comment: Most switches only break(on/off) the hot/live wire.  The neutral is not broken/switched.  Where the switch is does not matter if the wire reaches.  Keep it inline with a longer wire, make a switch loop.

Comment: @crip659 you mean like [this](https://imgur.com/a/7lMiL2K) ? Or does `switch loop` mean something specific?

Comment: A switch loop, the power goes to the light fixture first, then the live goes to the switch and goes back to connects to the light.  With a cable type, need a three wire cable now, with live to switch and switch live to light.

Comment: You can buy wired “remote switch”  extension cords. https://www.amazon.com/Woods-Indoor-Extension-Remote-Switch/dp/B000KKND86 is an example of one for US sockets/plugs (NEMA 5-15). You may be able to find an equivalent for your locale.

Comment: Thanks ! 
You should both post those as answers !

Answer (score 1):

Consider the variety of power taps and power strips on the market that include wired or wireless remote control ranging from motion sensors to phone apps to capacitative touch detection.  Many of them also include USB ports.  Just make sure to select a product compatible with the type of light bulbs in use.  You might even consider a new nightstand with a built in switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular extension cord.  Plug the extension cord into the wall.  Plug the inline switch cord into the extension cord.  So long as the extension cord is long enough to allow you to place the switch where you want it and the lamp cord is long enough to reach from the switch to the lamp, this will work as you want.

The diagram that you show essentially has the extension cord built into the switch cord and routed through the lamp.  Routing through the lamp is unnecessary though.  It just saves having to run the neutral wire to the switch (which doesn't need it).  Using a regular extension cord will save having to rewire the lamp.  More cord that way but everything is just standard parts.

Note that for the USB light, you can use a USB extension cord.

Another alternative would be to add an outlet at the bed.  That's something that a professional electrician could do for you.  That would allow you to plug the cord into a place where it could more easily reach the position where you want it.  It might be worth moving the bed away from the wall and checking if there is an outlet behind it.